# Unable to read Github Actions job's outputs from another job

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, github-actions

I have the following workflow in Github Actions, where I have a job that create some outputs and a dependant job that read those outputs, pretty similar to the [example from the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs):

```yaml
name: Sandbox

on:
  push:

env:
  POSTGRESQL_VERSION: "14.4.0-debian-11-r13"

jobs:
  setup:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      prod_tag: "steps.prod_tag.outputs.prod_tag"
      postgresql_version: "steps.postgresql_version.outputs.postgresql_version"
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - id: prod_tag
        run: |
          if [[ ${{ github.ref_type }} == "tag" ]]; then
            echo "::set-output name=prod_tag::${{github.ref_name}}"
          else
            echo "::set-output name=prod_tag::latest"
          fi;
      - id: postgresql_version
        run: echo "::set-output name=postgresql_version::${POSTGRESQL_VERSION}"
      - name: Show output variables
        run: |
          echo "PROD TAG: ${{steps.prod_tag.outputs.prod_tag}}"
          echo "POSTGRESQL_VERSION: ${{steps.postgresql_version.outputs.postgresql_version}}"

  show_outputs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: setup
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "PROD TAG: ${{needs.setup.outputs.prod_tag}}"
          echo "POSTGRESQL_VERSION: ${{needs.setup.outputs.postgresql_version}}"
```

However, in my example, it doesn't work as expected and `show_outputs` shows `PROD TAG: steps.prod_tag.outputs.prod_tag` and `POSTGRESQL_VERSION: steps.postgresql_version.outputs.postgresql_version`instead of the values set in the `setup` job, that should be `latest` and `14.4.0-debian-11-r13`. In the step `Show output variables` of the `setup` job I can see that the values are properly set, and I've tried several different approaches (setting the variables from the same step, not taking the value from the environment variable, etc) but with no success.

Any idea what can be wrong with my example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should surround the variables with `${{` and `}}`
try with:

```
outputs:
  prod_tag: ${{ steps.prod_tag.outputs.prod_tag }}
  postgresql_version: ${{ steps.postgresql_version.outputs.postgresql_version }}
```

instead of:

```
outputs:
  prod_tag: "steps.prod_tag.outputs.prod_tag"
  postgresql_version: "steps.postgresql_version.outputs.postgresql_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for a simplified version of the solution, refer following.

```yaml
name: Test
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  one:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      HELLO: "${{ steps.set-some-stuff.outputs.HELLO }}"
    steps:
      - name: one-1
        id: set-some-stuff
        run: |
          echo "HELLO=WORLD" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
      - name: one-2
        run: |
          echo "${{steps.set-some-stuff.outputs.HELLO}}"
  two:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: one
    steps:
      - name: two-1
        run: |
          echo "${{ needs.one.outputs.HELLO }}"
```